# sum of squares recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I have to write a recursive function sumSquares() that takes a non-negative (>= 0) integer n as a parameter and returns the sum of the squares of the numbers between 1 and n. Example:

```
>>>sumSquares(2)
5
>>>sumSquares(3)
14
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def sumSquares(n):
    if n==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return sumSquares(n-1)+sumSquares(n-1)
```

Can I also have an  explanation of what you did, I'm still in the process of learning recursion, and it would help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Are you taking a class on "Python, but only using recursion"? Because all your questions are from that class...

Comment: Recursion is two things: 1) A base case. 2) A recursive call of the function. You have the right idea, but a better base case would be n==1, since you don't care about 0. The else should be `return n*n + sumSquares(n-1)`

Comment: no we are just in the chapter for recursion, and im just struggling with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say you represent your function by S(x), x>0

```
S(x) = 1^2 + 2^2 + ... x^2
```

this can be written as

```
S(x) = (1^2 + 2^2 + ...(x-1)^2 )+ x^2

S(x) = S(x-1) + x^2.
```

Now for the program.

```
def sumSquares(n):
        return sumSquares(n-1)+ n*n
```

But the problem is this doesn't know when to stop. We have to give a base case that tells it when to stop.

You know that S(0) = 0 or S(1) = 1.

therefore

```
def sumSquares(n):
    assert n >= 0
    if (n == 0):
        return 0
    else:
        return sumSquares(n-1)+ n*n
```

Comment: `assert n >= 0`. pep-8 recommends spaces around operators: `n == 0`

Comment: `assert` does nothing if I run `python -O` mwahahahahah

Comment: @gnibbler: `assert` is for documentation purposes only, otherwise it should be: `if n < 0: raise ValueError("Expected non-negative number, got %r" % (n,))`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, also for unittests. Typically you should never use `-O` for running unittests

Comment: @gnibbler: It makes sense to run tests with/without `-O` flag to make sure that assertions in the code do not produce undesirable side-effects. `unittest` framework doesn't use `assert` statement to implement its `assert*` methods.

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't that be

```
return n * n + sumSquares(n - 1)
```