# Python program to find sum of squares of digits using a recursive function

Tags: python

I want to make a function that gets the sum of the squares of its each digits. Although, I have seen some solutions in the internet, the one I have seen is "getting the sum of the squares of its digits" but given a list. For example, instead of starting at the integer 133, they use [1,3,3] as an input. I tested this function and it works great, but I want to use an integer as an input and not a list.

Edit: For example the given is 123. So the function must return 14. (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2)

My idea is:

```
    def squarer(x):                           # where x is an integer (not a list)
        # <insert a recursive formula>
        # return the sum
```

Comment: You can make a list from the number
>>> n = 43365644
>>> [int(d) for d in str(n)]
[4, 3, 3, 6, 5, 6, 4, 4]

Comment: @Hauklan I have tried this. The problem with this is I cannot use a recursive function. For example, my current formula is, "return number_list[0] * number_list[0] + squarer(x[1:])". As you can see, I can access the first digit of the list, which is great. However, when I will apply the recursive function squarer(), I need to input an integer. In my example you can see I use "squarer(x[1:])"   x[1:] will access the remaining digits but take note that this is not an integer but a list. Using my current formula, the program will result to error.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks for all the people who participated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sum of squares recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023350/sum-of-squares-recursion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to make a recursive function is, to always square the first digit and then call the same function with the remaining digits.

```py
def squarer(x: int) -> int:
    if x < 10:  # trivial case, when x has only one digit
        return x**2
    first_digit = int(str(x)[0])  # extract the first digit
    return first_digit**2 + squarer(int(str(x)[1:]))  # recursive call
```

Here, I used the functions `int()` and `str()` to always access the individual digits and cast the the variable back to an integer.

Comment: Your solution was close to mine, and you completed the missing piece in my problem hahah. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jakeyyyy If my solution was the wanted one, it would b great if you accept the answer so that others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an integer as an input and transform it into a list.

```
arr  = [int(x) for x in input("Enter a number: ")]
```

and then you pass your list into your function.

```
def squarer(arr):                           # where arr is a list
        # <insert a recursive formula>
        # return the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your number to string so you can iterate by each digit. And after you can convert string to `list` or just convert each digit to `int` before you apply other logic

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, this code should solve your problem

It is not of the highest quality but it works :)

```
def sq(x):

    sum = 0
    while x > 0:
        y = x/10
        r = y*10
        r = x-r
        r = r*r
        sum = sum+r
        x = y

    return sum


print(sq(12))
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive and without any transformations:

```
def squarer(n):
    if n <= 0:
        return 0
    rest, first_digit = divmod(n, 10)
    return first_digit**2 + squarer(rest)
```